# Can FileVault show the login window as 'name and password', not 'list of users'?

Tags: macos, security, filevault, login

Normally, Mac OS X lets you choose to show the login screen as a list of users (you click to enter the password), or two text fields (you enter the username and password):
[image]

But, I use FileVault 2. So, when I first turn on the computer I'm greeted with the login screen (with a blue background).
This is fine, except for one thing: **It's a list of users.**
But, for a variety of reasons, I prefer the 'Name and password' style.

**Is it possible to have FileVault give a prompt for username and password, instead of a list of users?**

Comment: I´d suggest you don´t do that ;-) First of all, a honest finder needs to know the name of the owner and second of all, you should consider hiding the users you want to hide, like in this answer http://superuser.com/questions/98206/hiding-some-users-in-the-user-list-of-the-osx-10-6-login-panel/101108#101108

Comment: @Asumus I've got a message displayed in case the computer is lost and found, so I'm covered there. Here's why I want to use the alternative layout: 1) No mouse work required! 2) Slightly more secure (someone trying to get in has to guess a username *and* password).

Comment: but you *can* login just using your keyboard! You can arrow down to the user you want to log into, press "return", enter the password, "return", and your in; you can even select any user with the arrow keys and then hold down "alt" while pressing "return" to get to the username&password prompt. Oh and "esc" brings you back, in case you were wondering.

Comment: @Asmus That's true, but is's way more work than just tying a username, pressing tab, typing a password, and pressing enter. I am aware that the normal way is usable; my question is how to set it to use a username and password prompt. I know I'm being picky, but this seems like a basic functionality they should support...

Comment: Well in my case it´s just "down-arrow", "return", password, "return" (I´m on the top of my user-list); but if you have many users on your system, I can see your point. And to be quite honest, I don´t think I´m ready to mess around with FileVault 2 preferences just yet. ;-)

Comment: I answered below, but as an aside - pressing the first letter of a username should match the user that starts with that name, saving you some tabbing and arrowing.

Comment: → Nathan: did you ask for a security improvment of the EFI to ask **username** and **password** at http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm quoting this directly from a [post](https://discussions.apple.com/message/15823532#15823532) in [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/message/15702053#15702053) at Apple Discussions:

> This isn't a bug. This is the way FileVault-2's EFI boot authentication UI is built. When your Mac first starts up, EFI-boot takes over to decide what to do. It either continues to bring up the system to the typical OSX login screen, which is managed by OSX's system preferences, or it starts a special EFI pre-boot where it displays the FV2 unlock screen with the icons of designated OSX accounts approved to unlock the disk. Once you log on, the EFI unlock sequence carries forth your credentials, performing a single signon.
>
> I have submitted a UI request (not as a bug) to be able to either edit the EFI boot screen (look at /usr/standalone/i386/EfiLoginUI directory, none are editable using normal applications) or ask that a feature is included, probably in the FV system preference pane, to add a custom banner.

For now, there doesn't appear to be a way to change it.

Comment: Yes, I undestand that it is a different UI. I'm interested in changing it. Are you saying that isn't possible?

Comment: Aye, sorry - the rest of his post goes into a bit more detail that states that for now, it isn't possible to change it. I myself don't have FileVault enabled so I wasn't 100% sure of what you meant, but the part I quoted cleared it up for me. So, yes, for now - there doesn't appear to be a way to change it. I've edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Maybe FV2 authentication UI is able to do "Name and Password" but your system settings change is just not updating it... Have you tried `sudo touch /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EFILogin.framework/Resources/EFIResourceBuilder.bundle/Contents/Resources` after the change above? (You may need to disable System Integrity Protection).