# How to disable the Guest account on OS X El Capitan

Tags: icloud, macos, filevault, guest-account

About a couple of weeks ago, the Guest user account was automatically enabled on my Mac running OS X El Capitan (by itself, without me enabling it). Now, whenever I start my Mac, I am greeted with a login screen showing two accounts: 1) Mine. 2) Guest user.

I have Find My Mac turned off, as I know people have suggested that the Find My Mac feature may be responsible for this behavior. Beyond that, I have logged out of my iCloud account from "System Preferences -> iCloud," and also disabled the Guest account from "System Preferences -> Users & Groups." Now it shows the Guest user as off in System Preferences.

However, when I start my Mac, I'm still shown two accounts to log-in. And yes, I have tried and have successfully managed to log into the Guest account despite having disabled it in System Preferences.

This is very strange, and I was wondering if anyone has found a fix.

Additional Info which may help: I've never had this issue with any other versions of OS X prior to El Capitan. And I've got FileVault enabled, and it's been enabled since OS X Lion without this issue.

I'd greatly appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Did you turn off find my mac before logging out? Did you disable the guest both in its account as well as general login settings?

Comment: I turned of Find My Mac before I logged out. I also disabled the Guest account in System Preferences as an administrative user. Still haven't solved the problem. Do you have a solution?

Comment: Do you have FileVault on?

Comment: This happened to me before, with Mavericks. I wipe my computer every 4-5 months are so though, so it is no longer an issue. It was infuriating though.

Answer (score 1):

After some extensive testing (and multiple Time Machine restores--to verify that this fix works), I have found a solution. And it's pretty easy too, just don't do it on the go, or you'll wipe out your battery.

1. Visit Apple's dedicated website to download the [OS X 10.11.4 Combo Update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1868?locale=en_US)
2. Disable Find My Mac
3. **Ensure that you have disabled the guest user**
   [image: Disable Guest User]
4. Install the combo update

Poof! Guest is gone.

5. Re-enable Find My Mac, if you'd like.
6. **Disable guest user again, immediately after re-enabling Find My Mac**

And that's it! It works nicely with FileVault 2, Bootcamp, and Time Machine, so no worries there.

Comment: You don't actually need to install the combo update... Since you've File Vault enabled your login happens pre-boot on the EFI... disabling the Guest User won't update the EFI login screen. I found a way to force it to update, read this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/232352/36313 . It should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a duplicate of another question, this answer should help you: [Guest login got enabled even though FileVault 2 is enabled and Guest login is disabled](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29206/guest-login-got-enabled-even-though-filevault-2-is-enabled-and-guest-login-is-di?rq=1)